# Windows Phone StackPanel control alternative for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, windows-phone-8.1

I prototyped an app in Windows Phone 8.1 (WP)  I was able to create cool controls using the  which would allow me to put Labels and other controls inside a button and this would glue them all together.

I am now rebuilding the app in Xamarin.Forms (XF).
I am working around this issue for the time being in XF by using Absolute Layout but I fear and I am expecting this to fall apart over differnt phones, sizes and models.

I am certainly sure I am not the first to have this problem so I'm wondering how others have gotten around it.

Thank you :)

What I like doing in WP:

```
<Button Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="232,1,0,0" Name="BtnVisitorScore" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="220" Click="btnVisitorScore_Click" Grid.Row="1">
    <StackPanel Margin="-5,-30,0,0" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatchSettings.VisitingTeam.Name}" Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="180" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Arial" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VisitingTeamCurrentScore, StringFormat=N0}" Height="70" Width="180" FontSize="72" FontFamily="Arial" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout

Comment: G.Hakim.  I tried that.  It is not the same thing.  That is the vertical layout for the form.  It is not for "gluing" controls together unfortunately.

Comment: I am pretty sure that StackLayout covers all the features as StackPanel does I mean  what exactly are you not able to do can you elaborate

Comment: Effectively I want to create a custom control.  In the example I showed above there is a button with two separately bound labels on it and other such more complex controls.   When I rotate the phone or change the screen size they all stay in the correct position.

Comment: Of course, Xamarin's Button does not allow what you are trying to achieve here, XAML for WPF and Xamarin Forms has a lot of differences, I would suggest you check them out before you start doing this!!